# Why is this Max function returning numbers which are too big and that are not on list?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C# and kind of newbie in general. The program below is to print the longest sub-string in alphabetic order. The if loop finds these sub-strings. The problem I am having is with the public static void Max in which I would like to print the maximum value from a string. This string contains the length values of the sub-strings found on the if loop.  Max however is printing large numbers which are not in the list and is not making sense. Max will eventually return the max which I will use to print only the sub string which length matches Max. Code is below.

```
    public static void Max(string list)
    {
             //prints max lenght 
        int maxi = 0;

        {     
            {

                for (int a = 0; a < list.Length-1; a = a + 1)
                {

                    if (list[a] > maxi)
                        maxi = list[a];

                   //  Console.WriteLine(maxi);

                  }}}}
```

The original list value is:
[List Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZXE8.png)

Max function prints:
[Max prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMU5K.png)

Comment: This code does not compile. Please format it properly.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: What is "printing the maximum value from a string" supposed to mean? You are looping through the individual chars which can be implicitly convert to int. You are seeing the UTF-16 code points in the string.

Comment: Careful with the characterizations - you are the one laboring under the impression that a *string* contains integer *values*.  And of course, a [mcve] is one of the expected elements of a good SO question.  Note that this provides a great chance to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: @Plutonix I will post the whole thing

Comment: No need - you have your answer

Comment: cool, thanks everyone

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour] before posting again; it will help get answers rather than downvotes

Comment: It would be nice to get a critique along with down votes. The question wasn't clear and I hadn't post the entire code? I browsed the How to Ask before.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, format properly. Your code was also missing braces (hence, *not compilable*).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Max` function takes `string` as its input. This is strange. Better would be to take in a `List<int>`:

```
public static int Max(List<int> list) {
    int max = 0;

    for (var x in list) {
        if (x > max) {
            max = x;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

Console.WriteLine(Max(list));
```

But why not just use built in functionality instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(list.Max());
```

Comment: I am C# beginner - the version I have for lists does not have list.Max

Comment: @Hephaestus At the top of the file, add `using System.Linq;` - Max is a LINQ extension method.